# Storing historical data for ActiveRecord Objects in a separate table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to track positions and portfolio value over time in my portfolio in order to present them on a graph. My portfolio has many positions. Positions store stock price and quantity. Each position has many movements that either buy or sell quantities of shares of stock. The problem is my application updates the price every day to reflect current market prices. And I can also change the quantity to remove or add quantity of shares. 
I calculate portfolio value by taking the total of stock price x quantity for each position.

I want to be able to do two things 
1) Store values of portfolios over time and plot them on a graph
1) Store values of positions over time and plot them on a graph

```
class Portfolio < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :positions, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :movements, through: :positions
  belongs_to :user
  ...

class Position < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :portfolio
  has_many :movements, dependent: :destroy
  ...

class Movement < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :position
  validates :quantity, presence: true
  ...
```

I am thinking of creating a chart-object model that will simply take a snapshot/store the positions and portfolio values at the end of each business day and I can then use that model to populate a graph.

Is this the best design decision or is there a more efficient way to store/ track the historical data?

Comment: I don't think this is a state concept.  There is a theory of state machines and multiple gems in rails.  To me when you say state you say you have an item that can have multiple states (conditions) for instance, let's say you have a reusable keg, the state can be ready to fill, filled, priming, consigned, returned (needing to be washed) and then back to ready to fill.  What you've described seems to be that you need a new table or two - you want to store the daily  closing position, and perhaps share value, over time...that requires advanced models and daily data being kept